# Keep getting "Message: binary is not a Firefox executable" in PyCharm (Flatpak) under Fedora 37

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to get Firefox (installed via RPM) running using Selenium on my machine (Fedora 37) with PyCharm (Flatpak). I've installed Selenium via PyCharm, unzipped geckodriver to PATH and specified driver/binary locations using `Options` and `Service`. Whenever I execute the following code the error "Message: binary is not a Firefox executable" is thrown:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

firefox_driver_path = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'
firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'

ops = Options()
ops.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
serv = Service(firefox_driver_path)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I'm not sure where exactly I've done wrong.

I've checked the location of the Firefox binary with `which firefox` in terminal and it is exactly the same as that in my code.

Comment: does Selenium follow symbolic links?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the flatpak version of PyCharm. I've encountered the exact same problem and I was able to solve it by downloading and installing Pycharm from their website (not flatpak)